# Proper & efficient way of affecting specific tiles in a tiled map

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, grid-layout

As it stands, I have a tiled map which is a 2D array containing tiles. Nothing fancy: tiledMap[column][row]. Tiles are custom SKSpriteNode objects that contain tile type, whether it's traversable, etc.

Character movement from 1 tile to the next is pinned down & working great. But now I have hit a roadblock when trying to refactor character movement to be able to only move to a selected tile that is highlighted. These highlighted tiles would surround the character whenever he is selected.

The current broken highlighting of surrounding tiles is working through a nasty for loop that simply checks the tile on the right, top, left & bottom starting from the tile the character is positioned on. I managed to extend the ability to check tiles further out by a single tile but it looks like a highlight plus. I want to be able to highlight any kind of patterns I wish with ease. The tragedy is I can't figure out how to apply the ability to simply input tile patterns (maybe some numbers into an array?) that need to be highlighted. It's important because as the character grows in levels, he can have more complex patterns of tiles highlighted around him allowing for more versatile movement. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a recursive function with input parameters that indicate the tiles to operate on and depth of recursion and output would be an array of tiles to highlight. So the initial call to the function would include the start tile and depth, then subsequent calls would pass in the adjacent tiles and the depth - 1. When depth reaches 0 you can just return the tiles array and append it to the previous invocation.

This is a draft example. You'll need to provide your own implementation for `getAdjacentTiles` and `FABTile` is your custom tile.

```
- (NSArray *)tilesToHighlight:(FABTile *)tile withDepth:(int)depth {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (depth == 0) {
        return result;
    }

    NSArray *adjacentTiles = [self getAdjacentTiles:tile];
    for (FABTile *adjacentTile in adjacentTiles) {
        if (![result containsObject:adjacentTile]) {
            [result addObject:adjacentTile];
        }
        NSArray *tilesToHighlight = [self tilesToHighlight:adjacentTile withDepth:depth - 1];
        for (FABTile *tileToHighlight in tilesToHighlight) {
            if (![result containsObject:tileToHighlight]) {
                [result addObject:tileToHighlight];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Call the method like this.

```
NSArray *tilesToHighlight = [self tilesToHighlight:startTile withDepth:2];
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried figuring out how to apply this but I'm having some difficulty. Currently, I have a method that returns a tiles index as a CGPoint. How would I convert Fibonacci to work with the structure?

Comment: I updated the example, should get you close to a solution. This [example](http://www.stone.com/The_Cocoa_Files/Recursion.html) was helpful. I was interested to see how this would work because I need it soon :)

Comment: Works beautifully. My 'getAdjacentTiles' method checks every tile the standard way: check right, top, left & bottom tiles.